# How to perform bulk update set in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an array of objects containing, e.g: [{name: "name", "id": 123, brNo: 456}, ...], data that I wanted put it into oracle database by updating multiple rows with their corresponding like below:

```
UPDATE   STUDENT_BASE                     
SET   NAME    = :name
                                                      
WHERE ID      = :id               
AND   BR_NO   = :brNo
```

I was thinking of doing some kind of looping but not really sure how.

Comment: Where do you have the array and in which format ?

Comment: What version is your Oracle Database?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Oracle 18 or higher, you can use the [JSON_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62) function to query the json information into a collection

```
DECLARE
    TYPE student_base_rec IS RECORD
    (
        name    student_base.name%TYPE,
        id      student_base.id%TYPE,
        brno    student_base.brno%TYPE
    );

    TYPE student_base_t IS TABLE OF student_base_rec;

    l_json           CLOB
        := '[{name: "new_name", "id": 123, brNo: 456}, {name: "new_name2", "id": 111, brNo: 222}]';
    l_student_base   student_base_t;
BEGIN
    SELECT name, id, brno
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_student_base
      FROM JSON_TABLE (l_json,
                       '$[*]'
                       COLUMNS (name PATH '$.name', id PATH '$.id', brno PATH '$.brNo'));

    FORALL i IN 1 .. l_student_base.COUNT
        UPDATE student_base
           SET name = l_student_base (i).name
         WHERE id = l_student_base (i).id AND brno = l_student_base (i).brno;
END;
```